# Is it possible to select Kivy rendering device?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, kivy, gpu

Is it possible to select Kivy rendering device?

Here is what I got for first run

```
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <angle_sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.badf00dbad00)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'ANGLE (Radeon RX 570 Series Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (ANGLE 2.1.0.badf00dbad00)'>
```

After disable graphic card (on the same machine)

```
 [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
 [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <angle_sdl2>
 [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.badf00dbad00)'>
 [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google Inc.'>
 [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'ANGLE (Microsoft Basic Render Driver Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0)'>
 [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
 [INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (ANGLE 2.1.0.badf00dbad00)'>
```

I would like to use "Microsoft Basic Render" instead of physical graphic card.

Can I disable GPU only for Kivy?

Comment: You can try to use [KIVY_GL_BACKEND](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/environment.html) environmental variable.

Comment: I tried to use function Config.set('graphics', 'KIVY_GL_BACKEND', 'glew') with 'glew', 'sdl2', and 'angle_sdl2'. But still not work.

Comment: It's not meant to use with Kivy config but as a operating system variable, as described on top of [documentation page](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/environment.html).

Comment: Do you mean os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'glew'? It still uses physical one.